# Flask form POST request to populate rest of jinja2 template

Tags: python, flask

I have a Flask web form that "searches for members" using a free-text input field. I want to programmatically load-test this website using some command-line tool like `curl`, instead of mocking user behavior with something like Selenium.

Here is the Python backend:

```py
# test.py
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = 'SUPER_SECRET_VALUE'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    member_id = StringField('Member ID', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    form = TestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        member_id_field = form.member_id
        member_id = member_id_field.data
        # simulate doing something with `member_id`
        sleep(2)
        result = 'some result'
        return render_template(
            'test.html',
            title='test',
            form=form,
            result=result
        )
    else:
        return render_template(
            'test.html',
            title='test',
            form=form
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And here is the HTML form:

```html
<h1>Search for a member</h1>
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>
        {{ form.member_id.label }}
        <br>
        {{ form.member_id(size=32) }}
    </p>
    <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>

    {% if result is defined %}
        <h1>Result is: {{ result }}</h1>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

First, I start the server with `python3 test.py` and then use `curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"member_id":"123"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/test/` to try to send a member ID to the form to trigger the searching logic.

If I go to the website in a browser, I'm able to type in an ID and the `Result is:` section populates. However, using `curl`, I don't get anything back:

```html
<h1>Search for a member</h1>
<form action="" method="post" novalidate>
    <input id="csrf_token" name="csrf_token" type="hidden" value="BASDHSAHSADHASHDASHDAHSDH">
    <p>
        <label for="member_id">Member ID</label>
        <br>
        <input id="member_id" name="member_id" required size="32" type="text" value="123">
    </p>
    <p><input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
```

If `Result is:` populates, I know my form is working. So, the using-a-website approach works, but the command line does not. What could the issue be?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the most optimal solution as it doesn't account for the jinja rendering time, but you could add a layer of `flask_restful`, developing a REST API for the core data processing piece:

```py
from time import sleep
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_restful import Api, Resource
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = 'SUPER_SECRET_VALUE'

def get_data(member_id):
    sleep(2)
    return f'getting data for {member_id}'

class TestForm(FlaskForm):
    member_id = StringField('Member ID', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

class TestApi(Resource):
    def get(self):
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        get_data(data)
        return data, 200
    def post(self):
        data = request.get_json(force=True)
        get_data(data)
        return data, 200

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)

api_manager = Api(app)
api_manager.add_resource(TestApi, '/api/test')

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    form = TestForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        member_id_field = form.member_id
        member_id = member_id_field.data
        # simulate doing something with `member_id`
        data = get_data(member_id)
        return render_template(
            'test.html',
            form=form,
            result=data
        )
    else:
        return render_template(
            'test.html',
            form=form
        )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And then use:

```sh
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"member_id":"123"}' http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/test
```